# Linked List C: add node to beginning, unexpected '0' value

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to add a new node to the end of a linked list, I am able to add something, but when I print it out the node has a value of '0'. I thought this might be happening because I may have neglected to initialise a variable somewhere, or forgot to allocate memory said variable. but I can't get it to work.

Here is my source code:

*my Linked List/struct:*

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef char DATA;

struct Node {
    DATA d;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

*my printList function:*

```
void printList(struct Node **head) {
    struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *temp;

    temp = *head;
    printf("Linked list:");

    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        printf( " \n %d ", temp->d);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

*my insertNodeAtEnd to end function:*

```
// inset data at end

void insertNodeAtEnd(struct Node *head) {
    struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *currentNode, *temp;

    temp = newNode;
    currentNode = newNode;

    printf("Enter a Node to insert at the end of the list \n");
    scanf("%s", &newNode->d);

    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = newNode;
        currentNode = newNode;
    } else {
        temp = head;
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newNode;
    }

}
```

*and my main():*

```
int main() {
    struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *head = newNode;
    struct Node *temp = newNode;

    head->d = 1;
    int i = 0;
    printf("Enter 3 numbers");

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        scanf("%d", &temp->d);
        temp->next = newNode;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    insertNodeAtEnd(head);
    printList(&head);

    return 0;
```

sorry for any messy code, I'm still reasonably new at this

Comment: `for (temp= *head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next){
    printf( "%d\n", temp->d);
}` :: for() loops are your friend.

Comment: `void insertNodeAtEnd(struct Node *head)` And **this** is the place to use a pointer-to-pointer; not in the print() function.

Comment: `%d` and `%s` of `scanf` doesn't match `char` (aka `DATA`). You should change `typedef char DATA;` to `typedef int DATA;` if you want to enter a number. Then it makes matched input and output.

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/ehnF34)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a couple of mistakes. Firstly, you need to add

```
temp->next = NULL;
```

before line `insertNodeAtEnd(head);`. The reason your code might work without this line is probably because your compiler initializes the pointer to NULL by default. For example in GCC you program is crashing without that line.Second problem is that you are defyning `DATA` type as a `char`, but reading it as `int`. It may cause crashing your application if processor working with big-engian addresses. You should change it to

```
typedef int DATA;
```

and also change

```
scanf("%s", &newNode->d);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &newNode->d);
```

After that, change

```
while(temp->next!=NULL)
```

to

```
while(temp!=NULL)
```

because otherwise you are missing the last element. Then, you need to reorder a loop a little bit. This is the full working code with all fixes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef int DATA;

struct Node
{
DATA d;
struct Node *next;
};

void printList(struct Node **head)
{
struct Node *newNode;
struct Node *temp;
temp = *head;
printf("Linked list:");
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    printf( " \n %d ", temp->d);
    temp = temp->next;
}
printf("\n");
}

// inset data at end

void insertNodeAtEnd(struct Node **headPointer)
{
    struct Node *head = *headPointer;
    struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *currentNode, *temp;
    temp = newNode;
    currentNode = newNode;
    printf("Enter a Node to insert at the end of the list \n");
    scanf("%d", &newNode->d);
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
        currentNode = newNode;
    }

else
{
    temp = head;
        while(temp->next!= NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;

        }
    temp->next = newNode;
}
  *headPointer = head;
}

int main()
{
struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
struct Node *head = newNode;
struct Node *temp = newNode;
head->d = 1;
int i = 0;
printf("Enter 3 numbers: ");

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  if(i){
    struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->next = newNode;
    temp = temp->next;
    scanf("%d", &temp->d);
  }else{
    scanf("%d", &temp->d);
  }

}
temp->next = NULL;
insertNodeAtEnd(&head);
printList(&head);
return 0;
}
```

## UPDATE

I added a two more fixes. as @BLUEPIXY pointed out, there are a few more OP's mistakes. I've already spotted them, but I didn't fix it because they were not essential to what causes OP's problem. But, anyway, the mistakes are following:

Firstly, if the list is empty, function `insertNodeAtEnd` will not update pointer to the list because you are passing pointer to head of the list instead of **pointer of a pointer** to the head. It can be fixed by adding `**` to the function argument type.

Secondly, you don't need to allocate memory while printing a list. You obviously just copied the code to each function, even to functions which doesn't require inserting nodes (like `printList`).

The above script is updated script including these two fixes.

Comment: 1) at `insertNodeAtEnd` `head = newNode;` . This can not update the list.

Comment: 2) at `printList` `struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));` occurs memory leak.

Comment: @JoeKur. If my answer helped you, consider accepting it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY. I've already spotted that, but I didn't do so much details because it is not essential to the OP's problem. But, I fixed it anyway.